# Create view and Restore view in JSF 2

Tags: jsf-2

I am having confusion that in jsf 1.2 when restore view is called from view handler jsf 1.2 do not called create view method.

`super.restoreView(facesContext, url);` is callded from restore view method.

But in Jsf 2 when i am debugging the code i observe that when the same method is called this line of code,
`super.restoreView(facesContext, url);`

calls createview method with postback attribute true.

Can any one explain me the difference.

Comment: Why are you calling that methods by yourself? It's supposed to be done by the faces servlet.

Comment: i want to add an attribute in createview of windowId that why i have orrvide it.